Why is it said that IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER doesn't have a fixed size?
There are many sources including Microsoft documents that say "Optional header doesn't have fixed size and its size is stored at FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader".
But the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER structure is defined inside winnt.h as follows, and it seems that it has a fixed size (240 bytes for PE+ and 224 bytes for PE).
#define IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES    16

...

typedef struct _IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER {
    //
    // Standard fields.
    //

    WORD    Magic;
    BYTE    MajorLinkerVersion;
    BYTE    MinorLinkerVersion;
    DWORD   SizeOfCode;
    DWORD   SizeOfInitializedData;
    DWORD   SizeOfUninitializedData;
    DWORD   AddressOfEntryPoint;
    DWORD   BaseOfCode;
    DWORD   BaseOfData;

    //
    // NT additional fields.
    //

    DWORD   ImageBase;
    DWORD   SectionAlignment;
    DWORD   FileAlignment;
    WORD    MajorOperatingSystemVersion;
    WORD    MinorOperatingSystemVersion;
    WORD    MajorImageVersion;
    WORD    MinorImageVersion;
    WORD    MajorSubsystemVersion;
    WORD    MinorSubsystemVersion;
    DWORD   Win32VersionValue;
    DWORD   SizeOfImage;
    DWORD   SizeOfHeaders;
    DWORD   CheckSum;
    WORD    Subsystem;
    WORD    DllCharacteristics;
    DWORD   SizeOfStackReserve;
    DWORD   SizeOfStackCommit;
    DWORD   SizeOfHeapReserve;
    DWORD   SizeOfHeapCommit;
    DWORD   LoaderFlags;
    DWORD   NumberOfRvaAndSizes;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES];
} IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32, *PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32;

So what does it mean that it doesn't have a fixed size?
And in case I wanted to write a PE parser, isn't it possible to just use sizeof operator on these structures regarded to the type of PE, instead of parsing the SizeOfOptionalHeader field?

I have a suspicion that the IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY tables may be considered part of the header, including their virtual address and size. So, to skip over the header you would want to also skip over the table data. You should do some experiements to see if that's actually the case.

It may very well be that this may change. They might add additional image data directories and in that case the size will change. Just because currently it is the same always doesn’t mean tomorrow it will be so why not do what they say and use the value provided?

This is stated in the documentation for IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32 and IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64: "The number of directories is not fixed. Check the NumberOfRvaAndSizes member before looking for a specific directory." So, while the struct has a fixed size, the header does not
